# Quotients of pro-$p$ groups linear over a complete Noetherian local ring

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-groups

Let $R$ be complete Noetherian local ring with finite residue field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristic $ p $. We say that a pro-$p$ group $G$ is *linear over $R$* if it is isomorphic to a closed subgroup of ${\rm GL}_n(R)$ for some positive integer $n$. My question is the following:

> Is the class of pro-$p$ groups linear over $R$ closed under taking quotients? That is, if $G$ is a pro-$p$ group which is linear over $R$ and $\pi:G\twoheadrightarrow H$ a continuous surjective homomorphism, then is $H$ also linear over $R$?

It's true for $R=\mathcal{O}_L$ where $\mathcal{O}_L$ is the ring of integers for some finite extension $L/\mathbb{Q}_p$, cf. [Analytic pro-p groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/analytic-prop-groups/FC96FCA4B4EF667EC6F035513E11DB32). Any comments and references will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you ask for abstract isomorphism, or isomorphism with respect to the analytic topology on $\operatorname{GL}_n(R)$?

Comment: @ LSpice i ask for isomorphism as pro-$p$ groups.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $R$ be $\mathbf{Z}_p[\![t]\!]$, take $G$ to be the Heisenberg group over $R$ (upper triangular matrices of size $3\times 3$ with diagonal 1).

The map $e_{13}:r\mapsto e_{13}(r)=1+rE_{13}$ is a group isomorphism onto the center of $G$. But $G/e_{13}(pR)$ is not linear over $R$, because it has an infinite abelian $p$-torsion subgroup and hence can't be linear (as an abstract group) over a field of characteristic zero (such as the ring of fractions of $R$).

Comment: Thanks for your counter example. It seems that $H$ will be linear over $R$ assuming $H$ is just-infinite. (i.e. it has no proper, infinite quotient.)