# Just-infinite quotients of pro-$p$ groups that are linear over a complete Noetherian local ring

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, p-adic-groups

This question is a sequel to [Quotients of pro-p
groups linear over a complete Noetherian local ring](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440941/quotients-of-pro-p-groups-linear-over-a-complete-noetherian-local-ring). Recall that an infinite pro-$p$ group is called *just-infinite* if it has no proper, infinite quotient. One can show that any infinite finitely generated pro-$p$ group admits a just-infinite quotient by Zorn's Lemma.

> Question: Let $G$ be an infinite finitely generated pro-$p$ group which is linear over some complete Noetherian local ring $R$, and let $H$ be its just-infinite quotient. is $H$ also linear over $R$?

As mentioned before, it's true for $R=\mathcal{O}_L$ where $\mathcal{O}_L$ is the ring of integers for some finite extension $L/\mathbb{Q}_p$. I'm particularly interested in the case of $R$ being the ring of formal power series over a finite field of characteristic $p$.

Comment: See *On linear just infinite pro-p groups* by A. Jaikin-Zapirain (J. Algebra 2002, [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-8693(02)00024-8)).